# how to add an xml node based on the value of a text node

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I am playing around with an xml file found @ http://www.jsphylosvg.com/examples/source.php?example=2&t=xml

I would like to insert a node if the value of the node `name="Espresso"`.

E.g. I would like to change from:

```
<clade>
<name>Espresso</name>
<branch_length>2.0</branch_length>
</clade>
```

to:

```
<clade>
<name>Espresso</name>
<url>www.espresso.com</url>
<branch_length>2.0</branch_length>
</clade>
```

Based on the research I have done thus far I can use `xpath` to find the node that contains espresso *(this should work, but it does not?)*

```
import re, sys
import lxml.etree
f = open("test.xml", "r")
data = f.read()
tree = lxml.etree.XML(data)
if tree.xpath('//name/text()="Espresso"'):
    insert new child here
```

At this point, it should be possible to use use `lxml.etree.Element` to make the xml node, and use insert to attach them into xml document

However, while this sounds great in theory, I am unable to get it to work.
I would really appreciate any help/suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your XPath statement is not exactly right. Here's what I think you want:

```
>>> DOC = """<clade>
... <name>Espresso</name>
... <branch_length>2.0</branch_length>
... </clade>"""
>>> 
>>> import lxml.etree
>>> tree = lxml.etree.XML(DOC)
>>> matches = tree.xpath('//name[text()="Espresso"]')
```

Then to append the element after the matches:

```
>>> for e in matches:
...    sibling = lxml.etree.Element("url")
...    sibling.text = "www.espresso.com"
...    e.addnext(sibling)

>>> print lxml.etree.tostring(tree)
<clade>
<name>Espresso</name><url>www.espresso.com</url>
<branch_length>2.0</branch_length>
</clade>
```

**EDIT:**

Since your document has a namespace, you want to pass a namespace map to the XPath function and prefix the tag name with the namespace prefix, like this:

```
>>> nsmap = {'phylo': 'http://www.phyloxml.org'}
>>> tree.xpath('//phylo:name[text()="Espresso"]', namespaces=nsmap)
[<Element {http://www.phyloxml.org}name at 0x2c875f0>]
```

Comment: thanks. The code works great using your example DOC. However, using the actual file it does not appear to be working.

Comment: @Stylize - It's probably failing because the actual file has a default namespace.

Comment: @Stylize added info about the namespace

Comment: @jterrace, thanks again! I accepted the answer. Could you direct me to some background reading on namespaces? What is the benefit of having a namespace in your xml?

Comment: no problem. You should read the [lxml namespaces section](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces). For some background, maybe the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace)?